# Slim framework redirect back with post values

Tags: php, slim

Hello so I am working on a registration page. This is what my form looks like:

```
<form action="/user/reg-link" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="txt_un">
<input type="text name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And in my routes file:

```
$app->get('/user/registration', function() use($app) {
    $app->render('registration.html');
});

$app->post('/user/reg-link', function() use($app) {
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request()->post();
    if($request['txt_un'] == "") {
    // $app->redirect back with form still filled up
    } else {
    echo "good job";
    }
});
```

What I wanted to do is to redirect back to the form if `username` field is empty but the email field must still contain the value before it was submitted. How can I do that?

Comment: You could store the variables/values in a session and change your `registration.html` to `registration.php`, then add the following to your input fields - `<input value="<?php echo (!empty($_SESSION[the_post_key])) ? $_SESSION[the_post_name]; : ''; ?>"` (*Note: remember to use sessions, you need to start them - `session_start()`*)

Comment: Can't you simply add validation at the client side to check if username field is empty? This will save a lot of network traffic as well as time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slim framework come with flash() module. You can add these code

```
$app->flash('txt_un', $request["txt_un"]);
$app->flash('email', $request["email"]);
$app->redirect(your redirect path);
```

In your registration page, modify your code into this

```
<input type="text" name="txt_un" value="{{flash.txt_un}}">
<input type="text" name="email" value="{{flash.email}}">
```

Comment: Nice idea. Would try this. Thanks! BTW, I am using twig as my templating :)

Comment: Then use {{flash.txt_un}} and {{flash.email}}